# What information is there about the Doctors family

Tags: doctor-who

I am in the process of catching up on the full set of Doctor Who series. I have started with 9 and am finishing the current series before I cycle back to the original episodes and Doctors. In "the doctors daughter" a daughter is manufactured by a machine out of cells from the doctor. In that episode he mentions that she was not his first child. Does anyone know more information about his previous families?

Answer (score 10):

The Doctor's family is a complex issue. It largely depends on what you consider canon or not. The First Doctor had Susan who was refered to as his granddaughter. This implies that he had at least one child but this child is never seen nor directly referenced in the series. The expanded universe has a complicated and controversial take on Time Lord reproduction involving devices called [Looms](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Loom). This is covered in the novel, "[Lungbarrow](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lungbarrow)".

Comment: There have been a couple episodes in the new Doctor Who series where he mentions off hand that he had a family, but they were all gone now.  I don't recall him ever getting more detailed than the fact of their existence.

Answer (score -1):

The Doctor's father was Gallifreyan and his mother was Human. His first wife was Gallifreyan (we assume, as Susan grew up on Gallifrey) and he had at least one child, who then had Susan. Susan married David Campbell, and they had children together. We know that before the Time War he was a father and a grandfather, but afterwards, he was neither.

Comment: Sources? Any sources?